# Drupal database performance tuning - switching particular tables to InnoDB from MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, performance, drupal, innodb

I've got a drupal site that gets low traffic, but has tons of new content being added by a custom feed importer module. This module creates nodes and associated taxonomies for imported articles.

Currently, I believe ALL our drupal tables are MyISAM. I was considering switching the heavy write tables:

1. node
2. watchdog
3. sessions
4. accesslog
5. What other tables would you consider?

To InnoDB.

Do you think this is a good idea? Am I likely to see a performance gain? The reason I'm looking at this as part of my overall solution is that, on import, mysqld is running out of memory often and taking the entire system down. It ONLY happens on import.

I'll end up seeing things like this:

```
xml import at [01/Jun/2011:13:26:38 -0400] "GET /import/xml_import HTTP/1.1" 200
....
14:02:38 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 1049152 bytes)
```

The box is x32 so we are limited to the amount of memory we can allocate to mySql. We also have PHP, JAVA, SVN and more running on this box ... it's taxed as is. heh.

So, any input on performance tuning the db in general would be appreciated, I'm doing the research now.

TIA.

EDIT: (I've included my current my.cnf):

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql/tmp
#old_passwords=1
skip-locking
key_buffer = 2048M #doubled from 1024
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_cache = 5000
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 64 #doubled from 32
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_size = 1024M #doubled from 512
tmp_table_size=1024M
max_heap_table_size=1024M
back_log = 100
max_connect_errors = 10000
join_buffer_size=1M
open-files = 20000

interactive_timeout = 600
wait_timeout = 600

ft_min_word_len=3
ft_stopword_file=''
max_connections=1000

#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M

#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M


#log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysqllogs/slow-log
#long_query_time=2   
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#log-bin=/var/lib/mysqllogs/bin-log
#log-slave-updates
#expire_logs_days = 14
server-id       = 1 

[mysql.server]
user=mysql
#basedir=/var/lib  

[mysqld_safe]
err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
open_files_limit=65536
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could for example log watchdog messages to a different place, for example syslog (just enable syslog.module instead of dblog.module) or mongodb (http://drupal.org/project/mongodb). Also, try to pin-down which queries are actually slow. In another, similar question, it turned out to be a single missing index on a table from notifications module which extremely slowed down the whole import: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3021/bulk-update-got-slower-after-conversion-of-database-tables-to-innodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, InnoDB is slower than MyISAM as InnoDB is atomic while MyISAM is not. With the tradeoff of performance you gain data reliability.

If you can, disable indexes before import, you will see a performance gain. Its more efficient to rebuild the indexes all at once rather than for every single insert.

You do not want to configure mysql to exceed available memory. The memory settings are spread across several settings. You can use something like this http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl to determine how well your mysql install is tuned.

Comment: That general statement is not correct. InnoDB can, correctly tuned, perform much better on tables with many writes for example, due to row-level locking.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, this is why I'm proposing using InnoDB on the heavy-write tables. I will checkout the mysqltuner script now, thanks.

Comment: Row level locking will help in a situation in which multiple connections are in contention for the same table. If its an import process with a single thread, it wont make much of a difference.

Comment: Ah ok, interesting point. Perhaps I'll leave the tables for now and just tune the my.cnf.

Answer (score 3):

**[If you know for a certainty that the website will be low trafficked, by all means remain in MyISAM.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/should-i-move-to-innodb-during-a-planned-migration/2887#2887)**

*However*, should that pattern ever change and you become high traffic again, [you could configure everything into InnoDB for two major reasons](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/what-would-the-optimal-mysql-configuration-for-a-drupal-7-site-be/2367#2367)

**REASON #1** : InnoDB does row level locking. As for MyISAM, any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query executed will cause a full table lock. Even in a low trafficked website, the possiblility exists of two or more DB Connections Locking the Same Table. With InnoDB, that possibility is totally eliminated.

**REASON #2** : [InnoDB Caches Data and Indexes. MyISAM only caches Index Pages.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)

The key cache (sized by key_buffer_size) hold index pages for MyISAM tables. There is always disk I/O to read data from a MyISAM. A record read for the first time will cache the Index Pages used to find the row in to key cache. Subsequent lookups will find the key needed in the key cache, but there will always be mandatory disk I/O to get the data. With InnoDB, both Data and Index Pages Reside in the InnoDB Buffer Pool (size by innodb_buffer_pool_size). Disk I/O is dramatically reduced with everything cached in the Buffer Pool.

I have always recommended Drupal databases using InnoDB instead of MyISAM. [It is actually easy to convert using straight MySQL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/how-to-convert-a-database-from-myisam-to-innodb/4794#4794).

Until then, MyISAM is all the firepower you need, [especially on servers with modest RAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/253059/mysql-innodb-optimisation/253233#253233).